# Use generics in method with Entity data framework

Tags: c#, generics

I would like to create a method that I can pass certain generic information to but cant seem to figure out what to use when passing entity framework tables into it.  Here is a silly example to demonstrate not using generics but we would like to write a generic method which we could pass any entity data framework table type into.

eg.

```
    public void NotUseful(ObservableCollection<Account> account)
    {
        foreach (Account a in account)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(a.Description);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

James.

Comment: Are you using POCO entities?

Comment: No, in this instance these are types directly from the context.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  I'm going to assume you have POCO entities, because STEs are no longer recommended by Microsoft.  With that in mind, in order to make a generic method to handle any type of entity I would suggest having your entity classes implement a common interface.  something like `IEntity`, then you can just make your function signature `public void NotUseful(ObservableCollection<IEntity> entities) { ... }`

Comment: Or, to make it generic `public void NotUseful<T>(ObservableCollection<T> entities) where T: IEntity`

Answer (score 0):

By EF table type, do you mean `DbSet<T>`?

```
public void SomeMethod<T>( DbSet<T> dbSet )
{
    ...
}
```

Usage:

```
SomeMethod( dbContextInstance.Accounts );
```

Comment: Not sure - perhaps I do. If I can use that instead of the "Account" type in my example that may be it - thanks so far.

Comment: are you using a `DbContext`?

Comment: Moho - yes we are.  We have allowed VS to create the context directly from an existing database.  We then reference the various EF entities from this.